# What is the minimum number of packs of each ingredient needed without left over?

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

### Case 1

> Ingredients A (3 kg per pack), B (4 kg per pack), and C (5 kg per
> pack) must purchased in whole packs.
>
> Given that 1 kg of A, 1 kg of B and 1 kg of C are needed to make a giant bread. We want to make some breads.

> What is the minimum number of pack of each ingredient we have to purchase such that none is left over?

My attempt

- First, find the least common multiple of 3 kg, 4 kg, and 5 kg. The LCM is 60 kg.
- Second, find the number of packs of each ingredients.

  - $A=60/3=20$ packs
  - $B=60/4=15$ packs
  - $C=60/5=12$ packs
- Third, additionally we can find the number of breads which is 60.

### Case 2

Let's change to another recipe.

> Ingredients A (3 kg per pack), B (4 kg per pack), and C (5 kg per
> pack) must purchased in whole packs.
>
> Given that **2** kg of A, **3** kg of B and **7** kg of C are needed to make a giant bread. We want to make some breads.

> What is the minimum number of pack of each ingredient we have to purchase such that none is left over?

Here 60 cannot be divided by 7. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the minimum number of packs of ingredients $A$, $B$, $C$ that we need to buy are $a$, $b$, $c$ respectively.  Then the total amounts of each ingredient are $3a$, $4b$, $5c$.  Let $n$ represent the number of breads that are made.  Then $2n$, $3n$, $7n$ are the total amounts of each ingredient that are used.  Therefore, we require
$$\begin{align}
3a &= 2n \\ 4b &= 3n \\ 5c &= 7n. \end{align}$$

Since $a, b, c, n$ are integers, we must have $n$ be multiples of $3$, $4$, and $5$ as you had observed in the first question; the least such common multiple is $60$, therefore let $n = 60k$ for some integer $k$.  Then we get
$$\begin{align}
a &= 40k \\ b &= 45k \\ c &= 84k. \end{align}$$
So long as $k$ is a positive integer, $a, b, c$ are also positive integers; thus $k = 1$ gives the minimum solution, $(a, b, c) = (40, 45, 84)$ packs.  This makes $60$ breads as in the first question.

It is worth mentioning that we need to be careful:  if, for instance, the ingredient ratio had been $2 : 4 : 7$ instead of $2 : 3 : 7$, then we only need $n$ to be a common multiple of $3$ and $5$, since the second equation in the system reduces:
$$\begin{align}
3a &= 2n \\ 4b &= 4n \color{red}{\iff b = n} \\ 5c &= 7n \end{align}$$
This gives us $n = 15k$ and for $k = 1$ we get $$(a, b, c) = (10, 15, 21).$$

Answer (score 1):

In short, focus on minimum number of breads we need to make. Everything else follows from there.

To make a number of giant breads with given ingredients and quantities and no leftover ingredient, you need to ensure two things -

i) Considering each ingredient individually - you are purchasing quantity of each ingredient in multiple of what one bread requires

For example, if I can purchase ingredient $C$ only in multiple of $5$ kg packs and a bread requires $7$ kg, I need to purchase $35$ kg of the ingredient (making $5$ breads) or in multiple of that otherwise I would have leftover.

$5$ kg packs and $7$ kg required for a bread - so you need to purchase $7$ packs and you need to make $5$ breads.

ii) Now combining all ingredients - you are also purchasing quantity of each ingredient such that they can all make same number of breads.

Taking the above example, ingredient $C$ will have no leftover if I make $5$ breads.
But now if I take $B$, ingredient $B$ is available in $4$ kg pack and each bread requires $3$ kg. So ingredient $B$ will have no leftover if make $4$ breads and so purchase $3$ packs of $4$ kg each.

Ingredient $C$ requires me to make breads in multiple of $5$. Ingredient $B$ requires me to make breads in multiple of $4$. What does that mean? I of course need to make $5 \times 4 = 20$ (LCM) breads so I have no leftover of either the ingredient $B$ or of $C$.

Now if I combine $A$ into the mix, $A$ requires me to make breads in multiple of $3$ ($3$ kg packs and each bread requires $2$ kg).

That means I need to make $5 \times 4 \times 3 = 60 \,$ breads (LCM of $5, 4, 3$).

Now that we know the number of breads, we can find number of packs I need to purchase for each ingredient.

So to end it, for each ingredient, I find the minimum number of whole breads I need to make given how much is required for each bread and the package size it is available in. Then LCM of minimum number of whole breads I need to make for each ingredient gives me the number of breads I need to make. Rest follows from there.